# ROS ImagePtr and Image Compilation Confusion

Tags: image, compilation, ros

I am trying to create a publish a custom message that has two images. Here is the custom message file:

```
Header header
sensor_msgs/Image leftimage
sensor_msgs/Image rightimage
```

And here is the file where I try to publish the images from my stereo camera over ROS using my custom message:

```
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr leftmsg;
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr rightmsg;
leftmsg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "mono8", leftframe).toImageMsg();
rightmsg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "mono8", rightframe).toImageMsg();
stereo.leftimage = leftmsg;
stereo.rightimage = rightmsg;
stereo_pub.publish(stereo);
```

However, I am getting the following compilation error when I `catkin_make`:

```
    error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘duo_cam::Stereo_<std::allocator<void> >::_leftimage_type {aka sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >}’ and ‘sensor_msgs::ImagePtr {aka boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >}’)
            stereo.leftimage = leftmsg;
                             ^
    note: candidate is:
    In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/image_transport/publisher.h:39:0,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/image_transport/image_transport.h:38,
    sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >& sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >::operator=(const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >&)
     struct Image_
            ^
```

How do I correct this? I already am using the toImageMsg() function which I see online makes the ImagePtr into an Image, so not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/classcv__bridge_1_1CvImage.html) the signature of `toImageMsg` is

```
sensor_msgs::ImagePtr toImageMsg() const;
```

that is it does **not** convert the `ImagePtr` to `Image` (`CvImage` is used to convert OpenCV images to ROS images). This can also be seen by the fact that  you declared `leftmsg` and `rightmsg` as `ImagePtr`; if `toImageMsg` would return `Image`, this would not work.

To get the `Image` of a `ImagePtr`, just dereference the pointer. The following should work:

```
stereo.leftimage = *leftmsg;
stereo.rightimage = *rightmsg;
```